How to do in-app hosting for a local folder for an Android webview
I know that the Chrome browser won't let you use modules and imports inside a local folder if it is not hosted with something like Live Server. The Android webview widget does the same. My question is: Is there some built-in method for hosting a web-folder (that is also an asset) for an Android webview?
I am using Android Studio with Kotlin to develop an offline web-app in a webview.
